# How to access layer shapefile data in Mapbox JS

Tags: javascript, mapbox, tilemill

I've created a map layer in Tilemill (with solar potentials in U.S. Northwest) with polygons, each polygon containing some data points. I've then uploaded that layer into Mapbox where it's been integrated with a basic street map ---- you can see the Mapbox version here: http://goo.gl/9ItiXs (notice the polygon "Teaser" hover action in upper right).

I need to draw this map in my own page using Mapbox.js such that when one clicks on a point on the map, I can grab the solar potential data value for the point and make use of it in a form.

I can't seem to find this data anywhere in the data being passed to the click event. I was assuming that this data would be handy there in the click callback. How do I do this?

Comment: Okay, I found how to access the interactive layer's data, at least for what is set up, in TileMill, as the "Teaser" data:
`code`
map.on("click", function(e) {
 // the attribute name I was looking for was called ANN_DNI:
 console.log("layers:", map.gridLayer._mouseOn.ANN_DNI);
});
`code`
MapBox really needs to work on documentation for (what seems to me, of course) obvious use cases. There really ought to be an interactive event.getData method set on the map for any interaction.